# Android :RecyclerView doesn't scoll

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

This is my XML code and it's working well on Android 5, 6, 7 and higher.
I see that it's not scrolling on Android below 5.
i don't know that this problem is related to focus of RecyclerView or Device Memory

For example on Honor 4C it's not scrolling and some other phones are like Huawei on android 4.2.2 too.

It doesn't seem like the app or smart phone crashes, it's just not scrolling.

Here's my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="ir.example.app.Activity.BuyInternetActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/actionbar"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/parent_internet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

            <ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
                android:id="@+id/lbl_buychargecoe_1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="bottom|center"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="شماره موبایل مورد نظر را وارد کنید:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_contact_internet"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_phonebook_selected"/>


                    <ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Edtview
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:layout_weight="0.8"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/edt_buynet_phonenumber"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:maxLength="24"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:paddingStart="13dp"
                        android:hint="09 - - - - - - - - -"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:id="@+id/lyt_ownNumber"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Switch
                    android:theme="@style/SwitchCompatTheme"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorKipo"
                    android:id="@+id/switch_internetOwnNumber"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp" />
                <ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
                    android:text="شماره خودم"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
                android:id="@+id/txt_operator"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="bottom|center"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="اپراتور موردنظر را انتخاب کنید:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_buycharge_code_mci"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_64sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_64sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pin_mci_unselected" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_buycharge_code_irancel"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_64sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_64sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pin_irancell_unselected"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_buycharge_code_rightel"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_64sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pin_rightel_unselected"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/lyt_packages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:weightSum="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/card_border"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                        <Spinner
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"
                            android:id="@+id/spin_terms"

                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp">
                        </Spinner>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spin_terms"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:text="مدت زمان بسته را انتخاب کنید :"/>

                </LinearLayout>


                <ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
                    android:id="@+id/txt_selectedPackage"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:text="هنوز بسته ای را انتخاب نکرده اید"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lyt_packageContents"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:weightSum="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="0.33"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="مبلغ"/>

                        <ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.34"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"

                            android:text="توضیحات"/>

                        <ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="0.33"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"

                            android:text="حجم"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#ccc" />
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_internets"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_110sdp">
                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>



    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use **NestedScrollView** instead of **ScrollView** in your Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/parent_internet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

<ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
android:id="@+id/lbl_buychargecoe_1"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="bottom|center"
android:layout_weight="0.2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="شماره موبایل مورد نظر را وارد کنید:"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />

<ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="0.33"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"

android:text="حجم"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ccc" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_internets"
android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_110sdp">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **NestedScrollView** instead of **ScrollView** in your XML file
and set recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: not working again , i think that if im using NestedScrollView and ignoring this line Code : recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
it would works

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
aandroid:background="@color/white"
tools:context="ir.example.app.Activity.BuyInternetActivity">

<include layout="@layout/actionbar"/>

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/parent_internet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

<ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
android:id="@+id/lbl_buychargecoe_1"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="bottom|center"
android:layout_weight="0.2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="شماره موبایل مورد نظر را وارد کنید:"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />

<ir.exapmle.app.Widgets.Txtview
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="0.33"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"

android:text="حجم"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ccc" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_internets"
android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_110sdp">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please specify how it is answering question.